# How to tell if syslog.conf has a typo

Tags: logs, configuration, syslog

I recently did in fact have a typo in my syslog.conf file, but I had no idea initially why I couldn't restart the daemon. In Ubuntu, all I seemed to get was a FAIL message after a rather long wait period.

Without it running properly, I was curious, is there a way I could have figured it out without scouring random logs pointlessly before considering there may have been a typo?

Edit: I really felt like using service to start/restart/etc the daemon should have given more than FAIL. Perhaps it does and I just don't know where to look, but if another service had a similar silly issue, I'd hope to be able to figure it out easily as well.

Comment: This won't work with a `syslog.conf` file but you can use Python to check some configuration files. For example, `cp /etc/sysctl.conf .; python -m py_compile sysctl.conf`.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman Thanks, I definitely didn't know that one. Most of what I use automatically checks it's conf file or at least logs it, but that's where I got lost with syslog being what had the problem :P.

Comment: It is sometimes useful to start the daemon directly rather than via the service. e.g. `sudo syslogd` may print an error message to the console if it can't start.

Comment: Is your system really using syslog or is it rsyslog?

Comment: @slm In this specific case, this system uses syslog.

Comment: @DavidBaggerman Thanks, I'll tinker at some point and try that, but the system I have now is in production and my only maint window is 1am-4am.. so I'll put off tinkering a little while.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way to do this would be to use `syslogd`'s debug switch, `-d`. You can invoke `syslogd` manually like so.

First disable any currently running `syslogd`:

```
$ sudo service syslogd stop
```

Then run it manually with the following switches:

```
$ sudo syslogd -d -f /etc/syslog.conf
```

#### Example

I don't have a working `syslogd` accessible but it would be very similar to `rsyslogd`. Here I'm invoking `rsyslogd`:

```
 $ sudo rsyslogd -d -f /etc/rsyslog.conf
1647.845869757:7fab7df4b720: rsyslogd 4.6.3 startup, compatibility mode 0, module path ''
1647.846009627:7fab7df4b720: caller requested object 'net', not found (iRet -3003)
1647.846026890:7fab7df4b720: Requested to load module 'lmnet'
1647.846035733:7fab7df4b720: loading module '/lib64/rsyslog/lmnet.so'
1647.846155408:7fab7df4b720: module of type 2 being loaded.
1647.846167849:7fab7df4b720: source file conf.c requested reference for module 'lmnet', reference count now 1
1647.846178301:7fab7df4b720: rsyslog runtime initialized, version 4.6.3, current users 1
1647.846196912:7fab7df4b720: source file syslogd.c requested reference for module 'lmnet', reference count now 2
1647.848016526:7fab7df4b720: module of type 1 being loaded.
```

#### Testing

You can then use the command line tool `logger` to simulate messages of various types to `syslogd`. Again here I'm using `rsyslogd` as a stand in so the messaging will be different but the effect is still the same with either one.

1. Sending a test message

   ```
   $ logger -t testmsg "hello world."
   ```
2. Results

   ```
   2439.368194624:7f461fee9700: Message from UNIX socket: #3
   2439.368226046:7f461fee9700: logmsg: flags 4, from 'grinchy', msg Aug 20 03:07:19 testmsg: hello world.
   2439.368234458:7f461fee9700: Message has legacy syslog format.
   2439.368247194:7f461fee9700: main Q: entry added, size now 1 entries
   2439.368257698:7f461fee9700: wtpAdviseMaxWorkers signals busy
   2439.368271525:7f461fee9700: main Q: EnqueueMsg advised worker start
   2439.368283031:7f461fee9700: --------imuxsock calling select, active file descriptors (max 3): 3 
   2439.368305014:7f46206ea700: main Q: entry deleted, state 0, size now 0 entries
   2439.368329151:7f46206ea700: testing filter, f_pmask 127
   2439.368340032:7f46206ea700: Called action, logging to builtin-file
   2439.368354849:7f46206ea700: file to log to: /var/log/messages
   2439.368361837:7f46206ea700: doWrite, pData->pStrm 0x7f462480a310, lenBuf 46
   2439.368370439:7f46206ea700: strm 0x7f462480a310: file 5(messages) flush, buflen 46
   2439.368413234:7f46206ea700: strm 0x7f462480a310: file 5 write wrote 46 bytes
   2439.368424063:7f46206ea700: testing filter, f_pmask 0
   2439.368431098:7f46206ea700: testing filter, f_pmask 0
   2439.368437738:7f46206ea700: testing filter, f_pmask 0
   2439.368444401:7f46206ea700: testing filter, f_pmask 1
   2439.368450861:7f46206ea700: testing filter, f_pmask 0
   2439.368457433:7f46206ea700: testing filter, f_pmask 0
   2439.368464826:7f46206ea700: main Q:Reg/w0: worker IDLE, waiting for work.
   ```
3. Log file's message

   ```
   Aug 20 03:07:12 grinchy testmsg: hello world.
   ```

#### Another Example

1. Sample message

   ```
   $ logger -p daemon.warn "this is only a test."
   ```
2. Results

   ```
   2008.317255462:7f3d13a95700: Message from UNIX socket: #3
   2008.317287162:7f3d13a95700: logmsg: flags 4, from 'grinchy', msg Aug 20 03:00:08 saml: this is only a test.
   2008.317295844:7f3d13a95700: Message has legacy syslog format.
   2008.317307482:7f3d13a95700: main Q: entry added, size now 1 entries
   2008.317317586:7f3d13a95700: wtpAdviseMaxWorkers signals busy
   2008.317328948:7f3d13a95700: main Q: EnqueueMsg advised worker start
   2008.317339316:7f3d13a95700: --------imuxsock calling select, active file descriptors (max 3): 3 
   2008.317362187:7f3d14296700: main Q: entry deleted, state 0, size now 0 entries
   2008.317375008:7f3d14296700: testing filter, f_pmask 127
   2008.317386832:7f3d14296700: Called action, logging to builtin-file
   2008.317401184:7f3d14296700: file to log to: /var/log/messages
   2008.317409775:7f3d14296700: doWrite, pData->pStrm 0x7f3d17506310, lenBuf 51
   2008.317418935:7f3d14296700: strm 0x7f3d17506310: file 5(messages) flush, buflen 51
   2008.317454814:7f3d14296700: strm 0x7f3d17506310: file 5 write wrote 51 bytes
   2008.317466838:7f3d14296700: testing filter, f_pmask 0
   2008.317474391:7f3d14296700: testing filter, f_pmask 0
   2008.317481448:7f3d14296700: testing filter, f_pmask 0
   2008.317488503:7f3d14296700: testing filter, f_pmask 1
   2008.317495259:7f3d14296700: testing filter, f_pmask 0
   2008.317502407:7f3d14296700: testing filter, f_pmask 0
   2008.317509079:7f3d14296700: main Q:Reg/w0: worker IDLE, waiting for work.
   ```
3. This line contains our message

   > 2008.317287162:7f3d13a95700: logmsg: flags 4, from 'grinchy', msg Aug 20 03:00:08 saml: this is only a test.

When you're done, simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to terminate it.

#### References

- [syslogd man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/syslogd)
- [10.3 Testing System Logging with logger](http://eduunix.ccut.edu.cn/index2/html/linux/O%27Reilly%20-%20Building.Secure%20Servers%20with%20Linux/bssrvrlnx-CHP-10-SECT-3.html)